# Multiple buttons on an html page to reveal text step by step rather than simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, html, button, text

trying to create a list of about 7 questions with a click to reveal answer button next to each question.
only problem is when i click one button, it runs the entire js code and shows ALL the answers not just that particular one.

here is my code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Question 1 </td>
    <td class = "aligncenter">
      <form action="javascript:void(0);">

        <div id="reveal-space"> 
          <input type="submit" name="b1" value="1" class="submitbutton aligncenter"/>

        </div>
      </form>

      <script>

      $("form").submit(function() {

        $("#reveal-space").text("Answer 1").show();
          return true;

        });
      </script>

    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Question 2</td>
    <td class = "aligncenter">
      <form action="javascript:void(0);">

        <div id="reveal-space1"> 
          <input type="submit" name="b2" value="2" class="submitbutton aligncenter"/>

        </div>
      </form>

      <script>

      $("form").submit(function() {

        $("#reveal-space1").text("Answer 2").show();

          return true;

        });
      </script>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Question 3</td>
    <td class = "aligncenter">
      <form action="javascript:void(2);">

        <div id="reveal-space2"> 
          <input type="submit" name="b3" value="3" class="submitbutton aligncenter"/>

        </div>
      </form>

      <script>

      $("form").submit(function() {

        $("#reveal-space2").text("Answer 3").show();

          return true;

        });
      </script>

    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Question 4</td>
    <td class = "aligncenter">
      <form action="javascript:void(0);">

        <div id="reveal-space3"> 
          <input type="submit" name="b4" value="4" class="submitbutton aligncenter"/>

        </div>
      </form>

      <script>

      $("form").submit(function() {

        $("#reveal-space3").text("Answer 4").show();


          return true;

        });
      </script>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

how do i fix it to make it so that when the "1" button is clicked it doesn't reveal the texts to the other buttons ?
i may need to take an entirely different approach

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: fix the formatting of your code here, we cant' read it!

Comment: It looks like this is a psudo-code representation of what you're using so I'm assuming what you have is binding multiple anonymous functions to the submit event on the form.  You might try binding to the click event of specific buttons... if you can provide your markup html or a sample along with formatted Javascript we might be able to get a more specific answer.

Comment: im using the standard jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form needs unique ID, because when you are setting up your form submit function $("form") is selecting all your forms.

Try changing

```
  <form action="javascript:void(0);">

    <div id="reveal-space"> 
      <input type="submit" name="b1" value="1" class="submitbutton aligncenter"/>

    </div>
  </form>

  <script>

  $("form").submit(function() {

    $("#reveal-space").text("Answer 1").show();
      return true;

    });
  </script>
```

To

```
  <form id="form1" action="javascript:void(0);">

    <div id="reveal-space"> 
      <input type="submit" name="b1" value="1" class="submitbutton aligncenter"/>

    </div>
  </form>

  <script>

  $("#form1").submit(function() {

    $("#reveal-space").text("Answer 1").show();
      return true;

    });
  </script>
```

The changes are id="form1" and $("#form1")

Comment: i tried that but when i change the form names for the different buttons "form1, form2, form3" clicking the button doesnt do anything.

Comment: follow up question, if i wanted to make question 1s button show back up after clicking question 2's button, how would i do that. i tried using ".hide()" but that takes the answer away without bringing the button back.

Comment: That's because the button was removed. When you call .text("some text") it will replace the content inside the tag with the text. So your input is gone, forever.

To get around it you take the input outside of reveal-space. When button is clicked, $("#form1 input[type=submit]").hide() in addition to your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach: you can load in all the answers in hidden divs within the form element, and selectively show those divs by finding them in relation to the form that called the submit function, so that the other dormant form don't get triggered.

```
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $(this).find("#answer").show();
        $(this).find("#reveal-space").hide();
    });
```

Benefits: you don't need unique IDs, you only need one submit function, the text doesn't have to be contained in the jQuery.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phirephoenix/7jEr9/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="QnA">
 <tr>
  <td>Question 1</td>
  <td class = "aligncenter">
   <input type="button" value="Show Answer" data-answer="Answer goes here" class="submitbutton aligncenter"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#QnA :input").on("click", function() {
 $(this).parent().html($(this).data("answer"));
});
</script>
```

You don't need a form or any submits, just make everything self-referential (you actually probably don't even need an ID on that table, but I don't know what the rest of your page looks like).

Comment: This works great, except for when i change the table ID. I changed the #QNA to match the id of the table im using as well but that doesnt seem to work. is QnA some kind of predefined class ?

Comment: It's case-sensitive and you need the # on line 11 before the ID of whatever-you're-using to let jQuery know that it's looking for a thing with an id of whatever-you're-using.